# Поиск максимальной суммы в дереве Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, oracle-apex

Необходимо пройтись по таблице иерархическим запросом подчитав сумму у дочерних элементов (CRP_WORTH) + значение корневого(CRP_WORTH) и вывести корневой элемент у которого наибольшая сумма.

Я понял как проходиться по всему дереву:

```
SELECT * FROM CORP START WITH CRP_PID IS NULL CONNECT BY PRIOR CRP_ID = CRP_PID;
```

И как посмотреть элементы у конкретного корня (тут для примера у корня с 1):

```
SELECT * FROM CORP START WITH CRP_PID = 1 CONNECT BY PRIOR CRP_ID = CRP_PID;
```

Теперь я думаю, мне нужно изменяя **START WITH CRP_PID = K** , где **K** = индекс корня, получить дочерние элементы каждого корня и суммировать их, а потом среди них найти максимальный.

Предполагаю, что это делается через подзапросы, но не могу сообразить как мне взять сумму из подзапроса и потом от нее взять максимальное значение, а потом вывести строку с корневым элементом у которого сумма максимальная.

```
SELECT a.* FROM CORP a WHERE 10000 >  ANY (SELECT SUM(CRP_WORTH) FROM CORP b START WITH b.CRP_PID = a.CRP_ID CONNECT BY PRIOR b.CRP_ID = b.CRP_PID);
```

**Содержание таблицы CORP**
[image: Содержание таблицы CORP]

Comment: Воспользуйтесь первым запросом, который выводит все дерево, в вывод добавьте у каждой записи корень от которого начали, с помощью connect_by_root в итоге получаете таблицу где в одной записи корень и очередная запись к этому корню, оборачиваете его в следующий уровень запроса и делаете group by по корню, сортируете по сумме, оставляете первую запись

Comment: Спасибо:) Теперь смог сделать задание:))))